# Mutable Named Tuple - or - Slotted Data Structure

Tags: python, object-oriented, meta-programming

A [question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34573457/541136) on Stack Overflow asked for a mutable named tuple.

The naive answer would probably tell them they just want to define a custom object.

However, named tuples take up a lot less space than custom objects - unless those objects use `__slots__`.

Further, a namedtuple is semantically just a record of data (maybe with some functionality associated with it.) So what if we really want something like a mutable "namedtuple" then?

I present, for your edification, a MutableNamedTuple (lifted and somewhat modified from my answer):

```
from collections import Sequence

class MutableNamedTuple(Sequence): 
    """Abstract Base Class for objects as efficient as mutable
    namedtuples. 
    Subclass and define your named fields with __slots__.
    """
    __slots__ = ()
    def __init__(self, *args):
        for slot, arg in zip(self.__slots__, args):
            setattr(self, slot, arg)
    def __repr__(self):
        return type(self).__name__ + repr(tuple(self))
    # more direct __iter__ than Sequence's
    def __iter__(self): 
        for name in self.__slots__:
            yield getattr(self, name)
    # Sequence requires __getitem__ & __len__:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return getattr(self, self.__slots__[index])
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__slots__)
```

And here's some examples of usage:

```
class MNT(MutableNamedTuple):
    """demo mutable named tuple with metasyntactic names"""
    __slots__ = 'foo bar baz quux'.split()

>>> mnt = MNT(*'abcd')
>>> mnt
MNT('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
>>> mnt.foo
'a'
>>> mnt.bar
'b'
>>> mnt.baz
'c'
>>> mnt.quux
'd'
```

It is indexable just like a tuple:

```
>>> foo, bar, baz, quux = mnt
>>> foo
'a'
>>> bar
'b'
>>> baz
'c'
>>> quux
'd'
>>> mnt[0]
'a'
>>> mnt[3]
'd'
```

It even raises `IndexError` where apropos:

```
>>> mnt[4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 18, in __getitem__
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> for c in mnt: print(c)
... 
a
b
c
d
```

Help isn't too bad if you give a decent docstring:

```
>>> help(MNT)
Help on class MNT in module __main__:

class MNT(MutableNamedTuple)
 |  demo mutable named tuple with metasyntactic names
...
```

Thanks to the ABC's mixin methods we can reverse it, check its length, and check for membership:

```
>>> reversed(mnt)
<generator object Sequence.__reversed__ at 0x7ff46c64b678>
>>> list(reversed(mnt))
['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']
>>> sorted(mnt)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> len(mnt)
4
>>> 'a' in mnt
True
>>> 'e' in mnt
False
```

Because we don't define `__setitem__` or `__delitem__` we get the same behavior (`TypeError`, similar message) as tuples when we attempt to mutate it by index:

```
>>> del mnt[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'MNT' object doesn't support item deletion
>>> mnt[3] = 'e'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'MNT' object does not support item assignment
```

Perhaps this implementation of a mutable named tuple is even Liskov substitutable? We are not allowed to subclass `tuple`, because we use non-empty `__slots__`. If we just look at methods tuples have that `MNT` doesn't have, we only see a few methods we don't implement:

```
>>> set(dir(tuple)) - set(dir(MNT))
{'__rmul__', '__add__', '__getnewargs__', '__mul__'}
```

`__mul__`, `__rmul__`, and `__add__` all don't really make semantic sense for a fixed length data structure.

And `__getnewargs__` relates to pickling, but the object pickles and unpickles just fine:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(mnt))
MNT('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

I think this is rather clever - so I'm putting this out for your scrutiny and amusement.

<strike>Roast me!</strike> Review my code! And suggest improvements! (Maybe I could improve on the constructor? Maybe subclass the ABCMeta metaclass? Can I enforce a subclass to create a docstring? Should I assert that the number of arguments is the same as the number of slots? How should I unittest it? Etc...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some issues I noticed in your implementation.

- Currently you're simply iterating over `__slots__` everywhere, but this doesn't handle the case when [`__slots__` is a string parameter like `'bar'`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots). i.e this shouldn't result in three slots `'b'`, `'a'` and `'r'`.
- Your abstract base class `MutableNamedTuple` is directly instantiable.
- The `__init__` method only works with positional arguments and the caller has no idea about its signature and will have to peak into its definition all the time.
- There's no verification of the arguments passed, hence I can pass more or less number of items to `__init__` and it wouldn't complain(in case of less items we will get `AttributeError` later on).

The following modifications try to address the above issues using meta-programming and other features of Python 3:

```python
from collections import Sequence
from inspect import Signature, Parameter


class MutableNamedTuple(Sequence): 
    """Abstract Base Class for objects as efficient as mutable
    namedtuples.
    Subclass and define your named fields with __slots__.
    """

    @classmethod
    def get_signature(cls):
        parameters = [
            Parameter(name=slot, kind=Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD) for slot in cls.__slots__
        ]
        return Signature(parameters=parameters)

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        slots = cls.__slots__
        cls.__slots__ = tuple(slots.split()) if isinstance(slots, str) else tuple(slots)
        cls.__signature__ = cls.get_signature()
        cls.__init__.__signature__ = cls.get_signature()
        cls.__doc__ = '{cls.__name__}{cls.__signature__}\n\n{cls.__doc__}'.format(
            cls=cls)

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls is MutableNamedTuple:
            raise TypeError("Can't instantiate abstract class MutableNamedTuple")
        return super().__new__(cls)

    @classmethod
    def _get_bound_args(cls, args, kwargs):
        return Signature.bind(cls.__signature__, *args, **kwargs).arguments.items()

    __slots__ = ()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        bound_args = self._get_bound_args(args, kwargs)
        for slot, value in bound_args:
            setattr(self, slot, value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return type(self).__name__ + repr(tuple(self))

    def __iter__(self): 
        for name in self.__slots__:
            yield getattr(self, name)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return getattr(self, self.__slots__[index])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__slots__)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> MutableNamedTuple()
...
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MutableNamedTuple

>>> help(MNT)

Help on class MNT in module __main__:

class MNT(MutableNamedTuple)
 |  MNT(foo, bar, baz, quux)
 |
 |  demo mutable named tuple with metasyntactic names
 |
...

>>> inspect.getfullargspec(MNT)
>>> FullArgSpec(args=['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})

>>> MNT(1, 2)
...
TypeError: missing a required argument: 'baz'

>>> MNT(1, bar=2, baz=2, quux=10, spam='eggs')
...
TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'spam'

>>> m = MNT(1, 2, baz=2, quux=10)
>>> m.foo, m.bar, m.baz, m.quux
(1, 2, 2, 10)
```

Comment: Good catch on the `__slots__` being a string. Yes the ABC is directly instantiable, but fairly useless with no slots. Other points are quite valid as well. +1 (hmmm... if we use a mapping for `__slots__` we could also type-check.)

Answer (score 4):

This Python is mostly over my head — and Ashwini just gave a more complete answer — but I do notice this infelicity:

```
>>> x = MNT(*'abc')
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in __repr__
  File "<stdin>", line 15, in __iter__
AttributeError: quux
```

It's possible to create an object of type `MNT` which is un-`repr`-able! Definitely you should fix this. Either the constructor should throw an exception, or it should initialize the uninitialized slots to `None`, or at worst it should leave them undefined and you should change `__repr__` to return "incomplete tuple" or something. Having a `__repr__` that *throws* is just bad news, IMO.

---

And since you mentioned pickling: it doesn't work for *me*, even with a not-incomplete `MNT` instance. I'm guessing you have a more recent Python version, maybe? I'm on 2.7.10.

```
>>> x = MNT(*'abcd')
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(x))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1374, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/Users/ajo/env/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 77, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError("a class that defines __slots__ without "
TypeError: a class that defines __slots__ without defining __getstate__ cannot be pickled 
>>> pickle.__version__
'$Revision: 72223 $'
```

---

> Can I enforce a subclass to create a docstring?

Why would you want to? :) That's definitely a style choice that should be made at the style-guide or commit-hook level, not enforced at runtime by some random user code.

But if this is part of your style-guide, then yes, `pip install pydocstyle` and then `pydocstyle .` will do the trick!

Comment: That pickle error should be updated to note that it's the version of the pickle protocol that matters - pass a protocol argument to dumps: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps (or upgrade to Python 3) - the repr issue has no semantic mapping to namedtuple - probably best solved by preventing deletion of attributes - and using (i)zip_longest or checking the number of args in the `__init__` or `__new__`.